сесть или посидеть
In looking at imperfective/perfective pairs of verbs, I see
сидеть / сесть
and
сидеть / посидеть
Are there two perfective verbs for "to sit"?
Thanks.

Does it help? https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/26720/134

The imperfective counterpart of сесть is not сидеть; it is садиться.
There are in fact many Russian words for "to sit", mainly prefixed versions of these verbs. These also have a secondary meaning "to be in prison" and "to go to prison"
сидеть, посидеть - to be sitting.
садиться, сесть - to sit down.
отсиживать, отсидеть - to get numb by sitting or to serve out your time in gaol
сидеться: ему не сидится на месте - he can't sit still
отсиживаться, отсидеться: to sit it out (not take part)
высиживать, высидеть: to sit through something to the end
обсиживаться, обсидеться: to get used to sitting in one place
посидеть: to sit for a while
присаживаться, присесть: to sit down (take up a sitting position somewhere)
усаживаться, усесться: to sit down comfortably
рассаживаться, рассесться: to take your seats; to sprawl
But this is just a selection. There are a dozen or so others.
NB: I've just noticed that Wiktionary lists the perfectives of сидеть as either сесть or посидеть. I think this is wrong, unless you regard "sitting down" as being a kind of perfective counterpart meaning of "to be sitting". Conceptually, these verbs are related, but different in meaning.
